# Why is a giant caret appearing on the display/edit and buttons?

Tags: support, firefox

Whenever I edit an answer (not a question, it seems), I see a giant cursor on the side that only disappears when I force the cursor somewhere else. It's difficult to show because it blinks.

[image]

It also appears when I click the buttons at the top, but miss.

[image]

And because you'll ask,

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2)
Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
```

Comment: Actually the cursor is showing up in all sorts of spots, it seems.

Comment: What does it look like once you start typing?  Also, norepro on chrome.

Comment: Nothing happens when you type. It just keeps on blinkin'

Comment: Also, norepro on ie7...

Comment: Is it just me, or is there an extra large space below your comments?  Also, does the page jump up and down once or twice while you type comments?  Methinks somebody pushed an update that should have had a little more units tested.

Comment: Also, you don't have .NET 4.0 installed yet???  Why, I oughta...

Comment: I don't see the space you refer to. No page jumping. And I'm on a work machine that (unfortunately) strictly controls what is installed thanks to overzealous systems managers. I was lucky to get firefox (because I brought it in on a flash drive last year, shhhhh).

Comment: @Nick Craver respectfully, I don't feel this is support, but rather a bug. If it was like this from the beginning, sure I'd be inclined to think differently, but I've only seen this since today and I am confident that I'd've seen it with 700+ answers, most of which were from this browser which has not been updated since it was installed.

Comment: @glowcoder - This is an *ooooooold* bug, and not one from StackExchange...so it's better classified as support, given it's not *our* bug.

Comment: @Nick It might not be *our* bug, but it didn't exist on *our* site prior to today.

Comment: By the way, this is called a *caret*, not a cursor.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this is no longer an issue, so it did get fixed if a moderator would like to tag this as status-completed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an old Firefox version 3 bug.  Not just on this site.  Haven't seen it yet in 4 and 5 so it probably got fixed.

Comment: That may be, but it's never done it on this site before.

Comment: Hmm, you think bugs are supposed to have predictable behavior?

Comment: actually many bugs have predictable behavior. Especially the old ones. And, it would seem that the bug hasn't changed; rather, this site has changed and introduced the bug into it.